# selectively return a field depending on another field in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a collection - something like:

comments:
{ comment, owner, anonymous }

The documents might be:

```
{ comment "comment1", owner: "Frazer Kirkman", anonymous: false }, 
{ comment "comment2", owner: "Frazer Kirkman", anonymous: true }, 
{ comment "comment3", owner: "HoefMeistert", anonymous: true }.
```

I want to always publish the comment and only publish the owner if anonymous is false, or the user is the owner.

So the above would return this for Frazer:

```
{ comment "comment1", owner: "Frazer Kirkman"}, 
{ comment "comment2", owner: "Frazer Kirkman"}, 
{ comment "comment3"}.
```

and this for Hoef:

```
{ comment "comment1", owner: "Frazer Kirkman"}, 
{ comment "comment2"},
{ comment "comment3", owner: "HoefMeistert"}.
```

Something like:

```
Comments.find({},{'comment':1, 'owner':(anonymous || owner==thisUser)}}
```

Comment: I'm running this server side in a MeteorJS project.

Comment: doesyour schema look like this:    `{
        comment "comment1",
        owner: "Frazer Kirkman",
        annonymous: false
    },
    {
        comment "comment2",
        owner: "annonymous",
        annonymous: true
    }` ?

Comment: Refer to this link as I think you can just exclude top level _id field in mongo. Refer to this link->https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/

Comment: hi Sergei, no it looks like: `{ comment "comment1", owner: "Frazer Kirkman", annonymous: false }, { comment "comment2", owner: "Frazer", annonymous: true }` - that way the owner can still edit or delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an aggregation where fill the owner name based on the anonymous bit. You can do this with a [$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) condition statement.

When you supply some more information i can help you with the statement. But please supply a demo documents.

Comment: great - I managed `Comments.aggregate( [ { $project: { 'comment':1,  'owner':  {$cond: {  if: {$eq: ["$publiclyShared",true] }, then: "$owner", else: '' } } } } ] )`  -  which returns owner:"" when needed.  Thank you :)  Off hand, do you know how to not include owner, rather than including an empty string?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what HoefMeistert suggested

```
Comments.aggregate([
    {},   // match all entries
    { $project: { "comment":true, 'owner':  { $cond: {  
          if: {$and:[{$eq: ["$anonymous",true]},
                     {$ne: ['$owner',this.userId]}
                    ] }, 
          then: '', else: '$owner'          }        } 
                 }
    }
]);
```